# What is the smallest, legal zip/jar file?

Tags: java, exception, jar, zip

I hate generating an exception for things that I can simply test with an if statement.  I know that a zero length zip/jar will trigger an exception if you try to access it using the java.util.zip/java.util.jar APIs.  So, it seems like there should be a smallest file that these utility APIs are capable of working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to **ZIP** file format [specs](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) a zip file should at least have the central directory structure that is 46 bytes long + 3 variable fields (check the spec by yourself).

Maybe we should assume at least 1 entry that implies the file header for that entry.

Comment: (PlugIn/WebStart will reject any zip/jar that doesn't start with a an entry header magic number (for protection against GIFARs).)

Comment: No, the smallest legal/valid zip file is 22 bytes: `80 75 05 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`.   I don't know about jar files, though.

Comment: @Cheeso, isn't zip supposed to start with `PK` ... wherease `80 75` is not that... :S

Comment: @DimitryK - Those values are decimal. P=80 K=75.

Comment: @billpg I think that's supposed to be in hexadecimal or vice versa?

Comment: @Cheeso Hmm, smallest readable zip file for me seems to be `50 4B 05 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` (18 bytes).

Comment: A zip anyone cares about contains an EOCD though.

Answer (score 3):

You really should put this sort of code into a try/catch as there are many things that can go wrong when reading/writing files?

If you really must know the answer to this then try to add a 1 byte file to a zip and then see if that fails? It's easy code to go through a range of sizes from 1 -> 65536 bytes and add to a zip and see which ones fail?

Comment: The code is in a try/catch block. I don't like to write code that uses exceptions to catch a condition that is testable, though.

Comment: Your code must be really crap then, if you think checking the size of a zip is enuff and nothing else can be wrong. Let the zip classes do their thing and let them complain via an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Jar files need to have at least one entry. If you want to make an empty one make a manifest only jar.

See [JAR Manifest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest) for more info on jar manifests.

Comment: So, it seems like the smallest legal zip file will be smaller than the smallest legal jar?

Answer (score 1):

The smallest legal zip contains zero entries, and one "empty" central directory.

The bytes are:

```
 80 75 05 06
```

followed by 18 bytes of zero (0).

So, 22 bytes long.

VBscript to create it:

```
Sub NewZip(pathToZipFile)

    WScript.Echo "Newing up a zip file (" & pathToZipFile & ") "

    Dim fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim file
    Set file = fso.CreateTextFile(pathToZipFile)

    file.Write Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, 0)
    file.Close

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    WScript.Sleep 500
End Sub


NewZip "Empty.zip"
```

Comment: That may work for the zip program, but it seems to be unacceptable to the java.util.zip.* apis.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a quick test and the smallest zip that I could create and then read back with the java.util.zip APIs was 118 byte.  There may be a way to create a smaller zip file that is spec compliant and readable with the zip utility...

Answer (score 0):

```
final static byte[] EmptyZip={80,75,05,06,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00};
public static void createEmptyZip(String path){
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
        fos.write(EmptyZip, 0, 22);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```